# JQuery window resize for Elementor Pro popups

Tags: jquery, elementor

I'm relatively new to JQuery. I'm using Elementor Pro to build my website.

Problem Statement: Trigger Elementor popup content on browser resize.

The code I'm using right now is as follows:

```
  $(window).resize(function(){
  var win = $(this); //this = window
  if (win.height() < 768) 
  {
      elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup({ id: 1234 });
      alert("Resize detected!");}
  });
```

The problem: The popup doesn't trigger on browser resize. Can someone please guide me on fixing this? Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: console.log a value or two for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all the **$** symbol in your code with **jQuery** and make sure you are resize browser in **vertical** code:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
 var win = jQuery(this); //this = window
 if (win.height() < 768) {
  elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup({ id: 1234 });
  alert("Resize detected!");}
});
```